# Javascript stripping dots on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, sugarcrm

I am trying to send a get request to a url and the script it stripping the dots from form.phone_work.value it should be getting the phone number there.

This is a smarty template. I think I have to put php inside {} also, I am inside of an array 'javascript' => 'MYCODEHERE' I think that the commas are creating an issue as well because md5($_SESSION['asynchronous_key']) is inside a quote in an array.

This is the non-working code:

```
'javascript' => '<script type="text/javascript">
var host = "http://localhost/";
var currentUserPhone = "sip2000";
var session = "<? echo md5($_SESSION['.asynchronous_key.']); ?>";

function invoke_call(v) {
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to call:"+v)) {
var callback = { 
  success: function(o) {}
    }
var connectionObject = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest ("GET",  
   host+"/scripts/call_api.php?"+
   "dest="+encodeURIComponent(v)+
   "&ext="+currentUserPhone+
   "&key="+session, 
   callback);
 }
}
```

'

I know the form.phone_work.value works because I am using it on the button that calls this script. The phone numbers shows up in the confirmation box.

```
<input title="call" accessKey="{$MOD.LBL_SERVICES_BUTTON_KEY}" type="button" class="button" 
         onClick="invoke_call(form.phone_work.value)" name="call" value="Call Office">
```

This is the URL that is being generate. You can see where it is not parsing phone_work for dest=

```
http://localhost/scripts/call_api.php?dest=phone_workvalue&ext=&key=3989
```

Comment: You have a suspicious mix of php and js; you do realize that the php is only processed when the page is requested initially, right?

Comment: Seems to me you are applying erroneous PHP formatting to JavaScript

Comment: Updated the question with your comment and deleted my no longer relevant answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as shown has been edited and is the working code. The issue ended up being the session was being cached since this is a smarty template. I disabled cache for this particular view to correct the problem.